# Spinner submenu android

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, android-spinner

The user experience should be something like this:

1. user selects item from a spinner
2. depending on which item was selected, a submenu/dialog (multiple-choice) opens where user selects one submenu item
3. depending on the selected spinner item and the selected submenu item something is displayed

I tried to implement "2" as an AlertDialog, which kind of worked, but ran into the problem that "3" would execute before the user had selected an item from the submenu ("2"). As far as I understand, it is not possible to have "3" wait for the closing of the dialog (correct?).

Is there some way to implement a UI like this? I could probably implement "2" as a second spinner, but would rather not occupy more screen space, so am looking for a solution with something that disappears after selection.

Comment: Can you give an example of the code you have so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume #3 is code executing in the `AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener` from the `Spinner` correct?

If so just move your code to the `AlertDialog`'s `AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener` and check the selected item of the spinner with `Spinner.getSelectedItem()` or `Spinner.getSelectedItemId()`

Comment: Thanks. Exactly as you wrote.